# Building an RPM with MAVEN resolves in: "Symbol not found: nspr_use_zone_allocator"

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins

We are using the jenkins/blueocean docker to build rpm's with maven. We are currently getting this error when building an rpm.

```
Building target platforms: noarch-unknown-linux
[INFO] Building for target noarch-unknown-linux
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] RPM build errors:
[INFO] error: Failed to resolve symbol ima_hooks: Symbol not found: 
       nspr_use_zone_allocator
[INFO] error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
[INFO] error: error creating temporary file /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.XXXXXX: 
       Permission denied
[INFO] error: Unable to open temp file: Permission denied
[INFO]     Failed to resolve symbol ima_hooks: Symbol not found: 
           nspr_use_zone_allocator
[INFO]     cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
[INFO]     error creating temporary file /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.XXXXXX: Permission 
           denied
[INFO]     Unable to open temp file: Permission denied
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 54.026 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-28T11:04:56+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 52M/548M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.3:attached-rpm 
        (attach-rpm) on project wise-bxmas: RPM build execution returned: 
        '1' executing '/bin/sh -c cd '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/application/target/rpm/artifact/SPECS' 
        && 'rpmbuild' '-bb' '--target' 'noarch-unknown-linux' '--buildroot' 
       '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/application/target/rpm/artifact/buildroot' 
       '--define' '_topdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/artifact/target/rpm/artifact' 
       'artifact.spec'' -> [Help 1]
```

Tools we use to build:

- docker-engine: 17.04.0-ce
- docker-compose: 1.12.0, build b31ff33
- jenkins/blueocean docker : 1.0.1
- java: 1.8.0_121
- maven: 3.3.9
- maven-rpm-plugin: 2.1.3

I have looked on the Google but didn't find any relevant issues and/or solutions.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it. The actual cause of this problem was:

```
Unable to open temp file: Permission denied
```

I resolved by adding:

```
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/tmp/
```

to the Dockerfile. The build-user 'jenkins' can access the directory at this moment. Then RPM is build correctly.